# Error when running SonarQube in Jenkins Pipeline only when I run the sonarqube container in the pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, centos, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I am running SonarQube in a Jenkins pipeline (not using the plugin, I am using a container). I am using the docker image sonarqube from the docker hub, and start it by

```
docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 sonarqube
```

If I start the container from the command line and then go into the jenkins pipeline and do the following command the pipeline is successful and the analysis is complete.

```
mvn sonar:sonar -f /project1/pom.xml -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.projectKey=jenkins_sonarqube -Dsonar.working.directory=/project1/target/sonar -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/project1 -Dsonar.java.binaries=/project1 -Dsonar.sources=/project1/src -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=admin
```

However, if I start the container as a step inside of the pipeline, it fails. I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project project1: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to download libraries from server: INVALID HASH: File /home/user/.sonar/cache/_tmp/fileCache4167880655381045232.tmp was expected to have hash ";color:#e6e6e6}.capitalize{text-transform:capitalize!important}.cursor-not-allowed{cursor:not-allowed!important}.no-select{-webkit-user-select:none!important;-moz-user-select:none!important;-ms-user-select:none!important;user-select:none!important}.no-outline,.no-outline:focus{outline:0!important}.bg-danger{background-color:#d4333f;color:#fff}.bg-warning{background-color:#ed7d20;color:#fff}.bg-info{background-color:#4b9fd5;color:#fff}.bg-success{background-color:#0a0;color:#fff}.bg-muted{background-color:#f3f3f3;color:inherit}.leak-box{background-color:#fbf3d5;border:1px solid #eae3c7;padding:4px 6px}.shortcut-button{display:inline-block;min-width:24px;height:24px;line-height:21px;padding:0 4px;box-sizing:border-box;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:3px;background-image:linear-gradient(180deg,#f5f5f5,#eee);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 #fff,0 1px 0 #ccc;color:#777;font-size:11px;text-align:center}.shortcut-button-small{min-width:16px;height:16px;line-height:14px;margin-left:4px;margin-right:4px}.flash{background-color:transparent;transition:all .5s ease}.flash.in{background-color:#fcf8e3}.flash-heavy.in{background-color:#ffe456}.identity-provider{display:inline-block;line-height:14px;padding:2px 5px;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);border-radius:3px;box-sizing:border-box;background-color:#236a97;font-size:12px;color:#fff}.spinner{border:2px solid #4b9fd5;border-radius:50%;animation:spin .75s infinite linear}.spinner,.spinner-placeholder{position:relative;vertical-align:middle;width:16px;height:16px}.spinner-placeholder{display:inline-block;visibility:hidden}.spinner:after,.spinner:before{left:-2px;top:-2px;display:none;position:absolute;content:"";width:inherit;height:inherit;border:inherit;border-radius:inherit}.spinner,.spinner:after,.spinner:before{display:inline-block;box-sizing:border-box;border-color:transparent;border-top-color:#4b9fd5;animation-duration:1.2s}.spinner:before{transform:rotate(120deg)}.spinner:after{transform:rotate(240deg)}.spinner-margin{margin:10px}@keyframes spin{0%{transform:rotate(0)}to{transform:rotate(1turn)}}.global-loading{width:300px;margin:200px auto 0;white-space:nowrap}.global-loading-spinner{vertical-align:middle;width:80px;height:80px}.global-loading-text{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;margin-left:30px;font-size:36px;font-weight:300}.ReactModal__Content,.modal{position:fixed;z-index:6001;top:0;left:50%;margin-left:-270px;width:540px;background-color:#fff;opacity:0;transition:all .2s ease}.ReactModal__Content:focus,.modal:focus{outline:0}.ReactModal__Content--after-open,.modal.in{top:15%;opacity:1}.modal-medium{width:800px;margin-left:-400px}.modal-large{width:calc(100% - 40px);max-width:1280px;min-width:1040px;margin-left:0;transform:translateX(-50%)}.ReactModal__Overlay,.modal-overlay{position:fixed;z-index:6000;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.7);opacity:0;transition:all .2s ease}.ReactModal__Overlay--after-open,.modal-overlay.in{opacity:1}.ReactModal__Body--open,.modal-open{overflow:hidden;margin-right:15px}.modal-container{max-height:70vh;padding:10px;box-sizing:border-box;overflow:auto}.modal-head{padding:0 10px;background-color:#efefef;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd}.modal-head h1,.modal-head h2{line-height:30px;min-height:30px}.modal-body{padding:10px}.modal-simple-head{padding:40px 60px}.modal-simple-head h1{font-size:24px;font-weight:700;line-height:30px}.modal-simple-body{padding:0 60px}.modal-simple-footer{padding:40px 60px}.modal-field,.modal-large-field,.modal-validation-field{clear:both;display:block;padding:5px 0 5px 130px}.modal-large-field{padding:20px 40px}.modal-validation-field{padding:3px 0 3px 130px}.modal-field label,.modal-validation-field label{position:relative;left:-140px;display:block;float:left;width:120px;margin-right:-130px;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-left:10px;line-height:1;text-align:right;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis}.modal-large-field label{display:inline-block;padding-bottom:15px;font-weight:700}.modal-field .note{line-height:24px}.readonly-field{padding-top:5px;margin-left:-5px;line-height:1}.modal-field .Select,.modal-field a.icon-checkbox,.modal-field input,.modal-field select,.modal-field textarea,.modal-large-field .Select,.modal-large-field input,.modal-large-field select,.modal-large-field textarea{margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:10px}.modal-field a.icon-checkbox{height:24px}.modal-field input[type=checkbox],.modal-field input[type=radio],.modal-large-field input[type=checkbox],.modal-large-field input[type=radio]{margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:4px}.modal-field>.icon-checkbox,.modal-large-field>.icon-checkbox{padding-top:6px;padding-right:8px}.modal-field .Select,.modal-field input[type=email],.modal-field input[type=password],.modal-field input[type=text],.modal-field select,.modal-field textarea{width:250px}.modal-field textarea{max-width:250px;min-width:250px;max-height:50vh;min-height:24px}.modal-large-field .Select,.modal-large-field input[type=email],.modal-large-field input[type=password],.modal-large-field input[type=text],.modal-large-field select,.modal-large-field textarea{width:100%}.modal-large-field textarea{max-width:100%;min-width:100%;max-height:50vh;min-height:24px}.modal-validation-field .Select,.modal-validation-field input,.modal-validation-field textarea{margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:2px;width:250px}.modal-validation-field textarea{max-width:250px;min-width:250px;max-height:50vh;min-height:24px}.modal-validation-field .Select:not(.is-invalid),.modal-validation-field input:not(.is-invalid){margin-bottom:18px}.modal-field-description{padding-bottom:4px;line-height:1.4;color:#777;font-size:12px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis}.modal-validation-field .modal-field-description{margin-top:2px}.modal-foot{padding:10px;border-top:1px solid #ccc;background-color:#efefef;text-align:right}.modal-foot .button,.modal-foot button,.modal-foot input[type=button],.modal-foot input[type=submit]{margin-right:10px}.modal-error,.modal-notice,.modal-warning{display:none}.alert{display:block;margin-bottom:8px;padding:5px 8px;border:1px solid #777}.alert:empty{display:none}.modal-alert{margin:-10px -10px 16px;padding:10px;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-right:none}.alert-danger{border-color:#ebccd1;background-color:#f2dede;color:#a94442}.alert-warning{border-color:#faebcc;background-color:#fcf8e3;color:#8a6d3b}.alert-info{border-color:#bce8f1;background-color:#d9edf7;color:#666}.alert-success{border-color:#d6e9c6;background-color:#dff0d8;color:#3c763d}.alert-muted{color:#bbb;border-color:#ddd;background-color:#ebebeb}.alert-big{font-size:14px;padding:10px 16px}.alert-small{font-size:10px;margin-bottom:0;padding:2px 4px}.page-notifs .alert{padding:8px 10px}.page-notifs .alert:last-child{margin-bottom:16px}.issue-list{margin:10px 0}.issue,.issue-list{max-width:980px}body,html{color:#444}body{font-family:Helvetica Neue,Segoe UI,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1.23076923}.h1,h1{line-height:24px;color:#444;font-size:16px;font-weight:400}.h1 img,.h1 svg,h1 img,h1 svg{vertical-align:middle;transform:translateY(-1px)}.h2,h2{line-height:24px;color:#444;font-size:15px;font-weight:400}.h2 img,.h2 svg,h2 img,h2 svg{vertical-align:middle;transform:translateY(-1px)}.h3,h3{line-height:24px;color:#444;font-size:14px;font-weight:600}.h3 img,.h3 svg,h3 img,h3 svg{vertical-align:middle;transform:translateY(-1px)}.h4,h4{line-height:24px;color:#444;font-size:13px;font-weight:600}.h4 img,.h4 svg,h4 img,h4 svg{vertical-align:middle;transform:translateY(-1px)}.h5,h5{line-height:24px;color:#444;font-size:13px;font-weight:600}.h5 img,.h5 svg,h5 img,h5 svg{vertical-align:middle;transform:translateY(-1px)}.h6,h6{line-height:24px;color:#444;font-size:13px;font-weight:600}.h6 img,.h6 svg,h6 img,h6 svg{vertical-align:middle;transform:translateY(-1px)}sup{vertical-align:text-top}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom}em{font-style:italic}strong{font-weight:600}mark{background:0 0;color:#444;font-weight:700}.emphasised-measure{font-size:24px;font-weight:300}blockquote{border-left:3px solid #e6e6e6;padding:0 8px;line-height:1.5}blockquote cite{line-height:1.5;color:#777;font-size:12px}.small,small{font-size:92.30769231%}.big{font-size:123.07692308%}.zero-font-size{font-size:0!important}.text-left{text-align:left}.text-center{text-align:center}.text-right{text-align:right}.text-justify{text-align:justify}.text-top{vertical-align:top!important}.text-middle{vertical-align:middle!important}.text-bottom{vertical-align:bottom!important}.text-text-top{vertical-align:text-top!important}.text-text-bottom{vertical-align:text-bottom!important}.text-baseline{vertical-align:baseline!important}.text-ellipsis{overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap}.text-limited-small{max-width:8vw}.text-limited,.text-limited-small{display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap}.text-limited{max-width:16vw}.text-uppercase{text-transform:uppercase}.text-lowercase{text-transform:lowercase}.text-no-transform{text-transform:none}.text-normal{font-weight:400}.text-muted{color:#777}.text-muted-2{color:#b4b4b4}.text-danger{color:#d4333f}.text-warning{color:#ed7d20}.text-info{color:#4b9fd5}.text-success{color:#0a0}.monospaced{line-height:18px;font-family:Consolas,Liberation Mono,Menlo,Courier,monospace;font-size:12px}.menu{min-width:160px;padding:5px 0;list-style:none;font-size:12px;text-align:left;background-color:#fff;background-clip:padding-box}.menu:focus{outline:0}.menu.is-container{padding:5px}.menu-item,.menu>li>a,.menu>li>span{display:block;padding:4px 16px;line-height:16px;clear:both;font-weight:400;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap}.menu>li>a{color:#444;border-bottom:none;transition:none}.menu>li>a.rich-item{display:flex;align-items:center;border:1px solid #cdcdcd;border-radius:4px;margin:4px 10px;padding:2px 8px;white-space:normal}.menu .divider{height:1px;margin:6px 0;overflow:hidden;background-color:#e6e6e6}.menu>li>a.disabled{color:#bbb!important;cursor:not-allowed!important;pointer-events:none!important}.menu>li>a.text-muted{color:#777}.menu>li>a:focus,.menu>li>a:hover{text-decoration:none;color:#444;background-color:#f3f3f3}.menu>.active>a,.menu>.active>a:focus,.menu>.active>a:hover,.menu>li>.active,.menu>li>.active:focus,.menu>li>.active:hover{color:#444;text-decoration:none;outline:0;background-color:#f3f3f3}.menu>li>a.text-danger,.menu>li>a.text-danger:hover{color:#d4333f!important}.menu .menu-vertically-limited,.menu.menu-vertically-limited{max-height:300px;overflow-y:auto}.menu-vertically-limited.with-top-separator{border-top:1px solid #e6e6e6}.menu-vertically-limited.with-bottom-separator{border-bottom:1px solid #e6e6e6}.menu .menu-footer>a>span{border-bottom:1px solid #cdcdcd;color:#777}.menu .menu-footer-note{opacity:0;transition:opacity .3s ease}.menu .menu-footer.active .menu-footer-note{opacity:1}.menu-search{position:relative;padding:8px 16px 0}.menu-search .search-box,.menu-search .search-box-input{max-width:none;min-width:240px}.menu-search~.menu>li>a:focus,.menu-search~.menu>li>a:hover{background-color:transparent}.menu-search~.menu>.active>a,.menu-search~.menu>.active>a:focus,.menu-search~.menu>.active>a:hover,.menu-search~.menu>li>.active,.menu-search~.menu>li>.active:focus,.menu-search~.menu>li>.active:hover{background-color:#f3f3f3}.menu-message{display:block;padding:4px 16px;line-height:16px}.menu-header{padding:8px;font-size:12px;color:#777;white-space:nowrap}.divider+.menu-header,.menu-header:first-child{padding-top:3px}.white-page{background-color:#fff!important}.global-container{display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:100%;min-height:100vh}.page{position:relative;z-index:2;padding:10px 20px}.page:after,.page:before{display:table;content:"";line-height:0}.page:after{clear:both}.page-limited{max-width:1280px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px}.page-container{min-width:1080px}.page-wrapper{box-sizing:border-box;flex:1 0 auto}.page-wrapper-simple{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;margin:100px 0}.page-simple{width:400px;padding:40px;border:1px solid #e6e6e6;background-color:#fff}.page-header{position:relative;margin-bottom:20px}.page-header:after,.page-header:before{display:table;content:"";line-height:0}.page-header:after{clear:both}.page-header .spinner{position:relative;top:3px;margin-left:8px}.page-title{float:left;margin-bottom:0;line-height:24px}.page-actions{float:right;margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:10px;line-height:24px}.page-actions .badge{margin:3px 0}.page-actions .spinner{top:0!important}.page-description{float:left;clear:left;max-width:800px;line-height:1.5;margin-top:6px}.page-footer{min-height:60px;padding:10px;line-height:1.5;border-top:1px solid #e6e6e6;box-sizing:border-box;background-color:#f3f3f3;color:#595959;font-size:12px;text-align:center}.page-footer a{border-bottom:1px solid #d0d0d0;color:#444}.page-footer a:active,.page-footer a:focus,.page-footer a:hover{border-bottom-color:#cae3f2;color:#4b9fd5}.page-footer-with-sidebar{padding-left:calc(50vw - 360px)!important}.page-footer-with-sidebar .page-footer-menu,.page-footer-with-sidebar div{max-width:980px}.page-footer-menu-item{display:inline-block}.page-footer-menu-item+.page-footer-menu-item:before{content:"-";padding:0 4px;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none}.page-with-sidebar{display:flex}.page-main{flex-grow:1}.page-sidebar{width:30%}.page-sidebar,.page-sidebar-fixed{min-width:300px;flex-shrink:0;padding-left:40px;box-sizing:border-box}.page-sidebar-fixed{width:300px}.page-sidebar-sticky{width:320px!important;padding-right:0}.page-limited .page-sidebar-sticky{margin:-20px 0 -20px -20px;padding-right:0!important}.page-limited .page-sidebar-sticky .page-sidebar-sticky-inner{padding:20px 0}.page-sidebar-sticky .page-sidebar-sticky-inner{position:fixed;z-index:10;top:30px;bottom:0;left:0;overflow:auto;width:calc(50vw - 357px);border-right:1px solid #e6e6e6;box-sizing:border-box;background:#f3f3f3}@media (max-width:1335px){.page-sidebar-sticky .page-sidebar-sticky-inner{width:310px}}.layout-page{display:flex;align-items:stretch;width:100%;flex-grow:1}.layout-page-filters{width:260px;padding:20px}.layout-page-main{flex-grow:1;min-width:740px;padding:20px;z-index:50}.layout-page-main-inner{position:relative;z-index:2;min-width:740px;max-width:980px}.layout-page-side-outer{flex-grow:0;flex-shrink:0}.layout-page-side,.layout-page-side-outer{width:calc(50vw - 370px);background-color:#f3f3f3}.layout-page-side{position:fixed;z-index:40;top:30px;bottom:0;left:0;border-right:1px solid #e6e6e6;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden}.layout-page-side-inner{width:300px;margin-left:calc(50vw - 670px);background-color:#f3f3f3}.layout-page-header-panel,.layout-page-header-panel-inner{height:56px;box-sizing:border-box}.layout-page-header-panel{margin-top:-20px}.layout-page-header-panel-inner{position:fixed;z-index:30;line-height:24px;padding-top:16px;padding-bottom:16px;border-bottom:1px solid #e6e6e6;background-color:#f3f3f3}.layout-page-main-header{position:relative;z-index:3;margin-bottom:20px}.layout-page-main-header .component-name{line-height:24px}.layout-page-main-header-inner{left:calc(50vw - 369px);right:0;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px}@media (max-width:1320px){.layout-page-side,.layout-page-side-outer{width:300px}.layout-page-side-inner{margin-left:0}.layout-page-main-header-inner{left:301px}.page-footer-with-sidebar{padding-left:310px!important}}.component-name{line-height:16px;font-size:12px}.component-name:after,.component-name:before{display:table;content:"";line-height:0}.component-name:after{clear:both}.component-name-parent{float:left;margin-right:20px}.component-name-parent:last-child{margin-right:0}.component-name-path{float:left;clear:left}.component-name-parent+.component-name-path{margin-top:4px}.component-name-favorite{position:relative;top:-1px;margin-left:4px;padding:2px 0}.line-chart-legend{color:#4b9fd5}.line-chart-legend.line-chart-legend-1{color:#236a97}.line-chart-legend.line-chart-legend-2{color:#24c6e0}.list-group{margin-bottom:20px;padding-left:0}.list-group-item{position:relative;z-index:2;display:block;margin-bottom:-1px;padding:5px 10px;border:1px solid transparent}.list-group-item:last-child{margin-bottom:0}.list-group-item.active,.list-group-item.active:focus,.list-group-item.active:hover{z-index:3;border-color:#4b9fd5!important;background-color:#cae3f2}.list-group-item:hover{z-index:3;border-color:#4b9fd5!important}.list-group-item+.list-group-item{border-top-color:#e6e6e6}a.list-group-item{color:#444;transition:none}.list-group-item-heading{margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px}.list-group-item-heading:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.panel{padding:10px}.panel:not(:last-child){border-bottom:1px solid #e6e6e6}.panel-vertical{padding-left:0;padding-right:0}.panel-white{border:1px solid #e6e6e6;background-color:#fff}.panel-warning{border:1px solid #faebcc;background-color:#fcf8e3;color:#8a6d3b}.badge{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;height:20px;line-height:19px;padding:0 8px;border-radius:2px;font-size:12px;min-width:10px;letter-spacing:.03em;color:#fff;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;background-color:#4b9fd5}.badge:empty{display:none}a.badge:active,a.badge:focus,a.badge:hover{color:#fff}a.badge{border-bottom:none}.badge.is-rounded{padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;border-radius:50px}.badge-medium{height:24px;line-height:24px;letter-spacing:.01em}.list-group-item-heading>.badge,.list-group-item>.badge{float:right;margin:3px}.list-group-item-heading>.badge+.badge,.list-group-item>.badge+.badge{margin-right:5px}.badge-normal-size{font-size:inherit;letter-spacing:inherit}.badge-tiny-height{height:16px!important;line-height:15px!important}.badge-muted{background-color:transparent;color:#777}.badge-muted:active,.badge-muted:focus,.badge-muted:hover{color:#4b9fd5}.badge-ok,.badge-success{background-color:#0a0}.badge-warn,.badge-warning{background-color:#ed7d20}.badge-danger,.badge-error{background-color:#d4333f}.badge-danger-light{border:1px solid #ebccd1!important;border-radius:3px;background-color:#f2dede;color:#a94442}a.badge-danger-light:active,a.badge-danger-light:focus,a.badge-danger-light:hover{color:#a94442}.badge-focus{border:1px solid #faebcc;border-radius:3px;background-color:#fcf8e3;font-weight:400}.badge-focus,a.badge-focus:active,a.badge-focus:focus,a.badge-focus:hover{color:#8a6d3b}.badge-secondary{background-color:#b4b4b4}.outline-badge{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;height:20px;line-height:19px;padding:0 8px;border:1px solid #cdcdcd;border-radius:2px;box-sizing:border-box;color:#777;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;white-space:nowrap}.outline-badge.active{color:#444;border-color:#4b9fd5;background-color:#cae3f2}.outline-badge.badge-info{border-color:#4b9fd5}.outline-badge.badge-icon{padding-left:4px}.outline-badge.badge-icon svg{height:18px}.columns{margin-left:-10px;margin-right:-10px;overflow:hidden}.columns:after,.columns:before{display:table;content:"";line-height:0}.columns:after{clear:both}.column-half{float:left;width:50%;padding:0 10px;box-sizing:border-box}.column-half.column-one{margin:0 25%}.flex-columns{display:flex}.flex-column+.flex-column{margin-left:20px}.flex-column-half{width:50%}.flex-column-third{width:33.33333%}.boxed-group{margin-bottom:20px;border:1px solid #e6e6e6;border-radius:2px;background-color:#fff}.boxed-group>h2{line-height:24px;padding:16px 20px 0}.boxed-group hr{height:0;border-top:1px solid #efefef;margin:16px -20px}.boxed-group-header{position:relative;z-index:10;padding:16px 20px 0}.boxed-group-header>h2{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;line-height:24px}.boxed-group-actions{position:relative;z-index:12;float:right;margin-top:16px;margin-right:20px}.boxed-group-inner{padding:16px 20px}.boxed-group-inner:empty{padding-top:0}.boxed-group-list{margin-top:-8px;margin-bottom:-8px}.boxed-group-list>li{margin-left:-20px;margin-right:-20px;padding:8px 20px}.boxed-group-accordion{margin-bottom:8px;transition:border-color .3s ease}.boxed-group-accordion:not(.no-hover):hover{border-color:#4b9fd5}.boxed-group-accordion:not(.no-hover):hover .boxed-group-accordion-title{color:#4b9fd5}.boxed-group-accordion .boxed-group-header{cursor:pointer;padding-bottom:16px}.boxed-group-accordion .boxed-group-header>.alert{display:inline-block;margin-bottom:-6px;margin-top:-6px}.boxed-group-accordion .boxed-group-inner{padding-top:0}.boxed-group-accordion-title{font-weight:700;transition:color .3s ease}.tabs{height:20px;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;font-size:93%}.tabs,.tabs li{margin:0;padding:0}.tabs li{display:inline;list-style-type:none;font-weight:400;color:#777;vertical-align:baseline;white-space:nowrap;border:0}.tabs li a{float:left;color:#777;vertical-align:bottom;height:17px;margin:0 1px 0 0;padding:1px 5px;border-bottom:none;transition:none}.tabs li a.selected{text-decoration:none;color:#555!important;font-weight:700;margin:0 1px 0 0}.markdown-tips{font-size:12px;color:#777}.markdown,.rule-desc{line-height:1.5}.markdown.cut-margins>:first-child{margin-top:0!important}.markdown.cut-margins>:last-child{margin-bottom:0!important}.markdown blockquote,.markdown h2,.markdown h3,.markdown h4,.markdown h5,.markdown h6,.markdown ol,.markdown p,.markdown pre,.markdown table,.markdown ul,.rule-desc blockquote,.rule-desc h2,.rule-desc h3,.rule-desc h4,.rule-desc h5,.rule-desc h6,.rule-desc ol,.rule-desc p,.rule-desc pre,.rule-desc table,.rule-desc ul{margin:1em 0}.markdown h2,.rule-desc h2{font-size:16px;font-weight:400}.markdown h3,.markdown h4,.markdown h5,.markdown h6,.rule-desc h3,.rule-desc h4,.rule-desc h5,.rule-desc h6{font-size:13px;font-weight:600}.markdown code,.markdown pre,.rule-desc code,.rule-desc pre{font-family:Consolas,Liberation Mono,Menlo,Courier,monospace;font-size:12px}.markdown pre,.rule-desc pre{padding:10px;border-top:1px solid #e6e6e6;border-bottom:1px solid #e6e6e6;line-height:18px;overflow:auto}.markdown code,.rule-desc code{padding:.2em .45em;margin:0;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.06);border-radius:3px;white-space:nowrap}.markdown pre>code,.rule-desc pre>code{padding:0;background-color:transparent;white-space:pre}.markdown blockquote,.rule-desc blockquote{line-height:1.5;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px}.markdown ul,.rule-desc ul{padding-left:40px;list-style:disc}.markdown li>ul,.rule-desc li>ul{margin:.3em 0}.markdown ol,.rule-desc ol{padding-left:40px;list-style:decimal}.markdown table,.rule-desc table{min-width:50%;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #e6e6e6}.markdown th,.rule-desc th{background-color:#f3f3f3;font-weight:600;text-align:center}.markdown td,.markdown th,.rule-desc td,.rule-desc th{padding:5px 10px;border:1px solid #e6e6e6}.property p{margin-top:10px}.coding-rules-detail-parameter pre,.property pre{display:inline-block;min-width:100%;margin:10px 0!important;padding:10px!important;border:1px dashed #aaa;box-sizing:border-box;font-size:12px;font-family:Consolas,Liberation Mono,Menlo,Courier,monospace}.coding-rules-detail-parameter blockquote,.property blockquote{margin-top:10px;padding:10px}.property ul{list-style-type:disc}.property ol,.property ul{list-style-position:inside;margin:10px}.property ol{list-style-type:decimal}.width100{width:100%}textarea.width100{width:100%;box-sizing:border-box}.property{margin-bottom:10px}.property h3{float:none;max-width:20em}.property>td,.property>th{vertical-align:top;padding:10px}.property>th{text-align:right}.property table.data{width:480px}.property textarea{vertical-align:text-top}.property .note{margin-top:5px}@media print{.noprint{display:none!important}a{color:#444;border-bottom:none}.page-footer{display:none!important}body,html{background-color:#fff!important}.widget tfoot,.widget thead{display:table-row-group}}.code .a{color:olive}.code .c{color:#660e80;font-style:normal;font-weight:700}.code .j{color:#666;font-style:normal}.code .cd,.code .cppd{color:#666;font-style:italic}.code .k{color:#0071ba;font-weight:600}.code .s{color:#277b31;font-weight:400}.code .h{color:navy;font-weight:400}.code .p{color:#347235;font-weight:400}.sym{cursor:hand;cursor:pointer}.highlighted{background-color:#b3d4ff;animation:highlightedFadeIn .3s forwards}@keyframes highlightedFadeIn{0%{background-color:transparent}to{background-color:#b3d4ff}}.clearfix:after,.clearfix:before{display:table;content:"";line-height:0}.clearfix:after{clear:both}.dropdown{position:relative;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle}.dropdown-bottom-hint{line-height:16px;margin-bottom:-5px;padding:5px 10px;border-top:1px solid #e6e6e6;background-color:#f3f3f3;color:#777;font-size:11px}</style></head><body><div id="content"><div class="global-loading"><i class="spinner global-loading-spinner"></i> <span class="global-loading-text">Loading...</span></div></div><script>window.baseUrl = ''; but was downloaded with hash cafb3aea4e5e50a93e31d7df29d26b12 -> [Help 1]

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project project1: Unable to execute SonarQube
```

It seems like the hash it downloads is the html of connecting to localhost:9000 when it should be: cafb3aea4e5e50a93e31d7df29d26b12

When I run the container in the pipeline and it fails, I comment out the line and try building the pipeline again it is successful. (aka using the same container that it failed previously on). I have a step in the pipeline that waits until it connects to localhost:9000 to ensure sonarqube has loaded before it tries to build my project.

Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a timing issue. I set the pipeline to sleep for 60 seconds and it worked.